# Regex add 0 after first decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I am currently learning regex but need this quite urgently.

I have a set of values `(10, 19.5, 13.99, 9.09)`. These formats are fine except for the second value.

My problem is how to rewrite so that 19.5 becomes `19.50` without affecting the other entries i.e `(10, 19.50, 13.99, 9.09)`

Many thanks guys.

Comment: as long as it's a number variable, the zeros to the right (after the decimal point) will get removed, unless you want them as String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are numbers, use toFixed()

If these are strings, you can use

```
num="19.5"
num.replace(/^(\d+\.\d)$/,"$10");
```

Comment: Or convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var num = 19.9;
if(String(num).indexOf('.')>-1)
{
    num = num.toFixed(2);
}
alert(num);
</script>
```

The straight answer is to use ".toFixed(2)", but we verify if it is a decimal so that we don't have results like "10.00"

For further formatting options you have the jquery plugin numberformatter:

```
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter
```

Here is the project webpage:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

The direct link for this library:

http://jquery-numberformatter.googlecode.com/files/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.2.jsmin.js

Comment: That would change `10` to `10.00`, but I suppose it is easy to check for an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use RegEx you could do something like:

```
"10, 19.5, 13.99, 9.09".replace(/^\d+\.\d{1}$/g, function (full) {
    return full + "0";
});
```

This would return `"10, 19.50, 13.99, 9.09"`.

Comment: This is incorrect. First, enable the `/g` specifier. This will replace 13.99 with 13.909.

Comment: This is the same as `.replace(/^\d+\.\d{1}$/g, '$&0')` - you don't need the callback function in this case. Also, `$` would only match the last position (it is correct if the input is a single number, not the whole list), and `{1}` does nothing by definition. I suggest you run the code and see its result...

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
(\.\d)(\D|$)
```

That's dot followed by one number, then something that isn't a number (or end of string).

Replace with:

```
$10$2
```

That's the first capture group, then '0', then the second capture group.

```
var s = '10, 19.5, 13.99, 9.9';
s = s.replace(/(\.\d)(\D|$)/g, '$10$2');
// s == '10, 19.50, 13.99, 9.90'
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, iterating each value:

```
var value = '19.5';
value = value.replace(/^\d+[\.,]\d{1}$/, '$&0');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var array = [10, 19.5, 13.99, 9.09];
for(var i=0; i< array.length;i++){
    if(/[0-9].[0-9]{1}$/.test(array[i]))  array[i] = array[i]+'0';
}
alert(array);

OUTPUT : 

10, 19.50, 13.99, 9.09
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/M9hZx/